# perl csv append column issue

Tags: perl, csv

How should I append an extra column at the end of a csv file using perl? I can't use `Text::CSV` as I'm using version 5.8.8 and the package is not installed here. I can't upgrade to a newer perl version. I'm first combining several smaller CSV files into one and then I need to add an extra column to that final file. I have declared the handle of the final file as SUB.

Here's my code snippet:

```
my $file = "/tmp/Sub_test_".$row.".csv";
        # the $row is in a loop..so it comes as 1,2 etc.
        open my $fh, "<", $file;
        <$fh> unless $file eq "/tmp/Sub_test_1.csv";
        print SUB while <$fh>;
```

I need to add an extra column with the header "count" and the value should be `$row`.

Comment: Why not ask your sysadmin to install Text::CSV? What's the point in using Perl if you're going to cut yourself off from most of its power?

Comment: yea..that's not going to happen anytime soon. They'll upgrade the entire system later and so I'm stuck with the older version :(

Comment: Companies only get away with stuff like this because the programmers let them.

Comment: If you need a module that isn't installed, try using local::lib
http://search.cpan.org/~haarg/local-lib-2.000015/lib/local/lib.pm

Comment: I can't install new modules.

Comment: You don't need any administrator or root rights to install local::lib. http://scratching.psybermonkey.net/2010/03/perl-how-to-install-perl-module-without.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it just a row count you want to add?

This appends **,count** to the first line and **,$.** (which is the line number) to the rest.

Then try

```
$ perl -e 'while (<>){chomp;if ($. ==1){print "$_,count\n"} else {print "$_,".($.-1)."\n"}}' your.csv


tmp.csv
one,two,three
4,5,6
2,3,4
6,7,1

$ perl -e 'while (<>){chomp;if ($. ==1){print "$_,count\n"} else {print "$_,".($.-1)."\n"}}' tmp.csv

one,two,three,count
4,5,6,1
2,3,4,2
6,7,1,3
```

Comment: I actually want to add just the $row value

Comment: The above code works. Thank you. However, I need it to reflect in the csv file itself which doesn't happen.

Comment: Can you read the old file and write to a new one? You can rename the new file once you're done. So you'd have something like
while(<OLD>){chomp;if ($. ==1){print NEW "$_,count\n"} else {print NEW "$_,".($.-1)."\n"}}'

Comment: yea, I did just that. Thank you for your help.